# Sort on a custom field in a yii CGridView

Tags: php, sql, yii, cgridview

I know similar questions has been already posted but I can't find my solution... 
My goal is to have a sortable custom column. (build from a function in my model.)
The column is correctly filled, the header is clickable but I have an sql exception when I try to sort.

here is my code :

So I have a CGridView in my view :

```
[code]
$dataprovider = $parametre->searchByUser($user->Id_User,'validateur');

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'ValidIndice-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataprovider,
        'rowCssClassExpression'=>'$data->color',
        'selectableRows'=>1,
        'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){ location.href = "'.$this->createUrl('Parametre/view').'/id/"+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}', //array('idEvent'=>$evenement->Id_Evenements),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view mgrid_table'),

        'columns'=>array(

                array(
                        'name'=>'Libelle',
                        'header'=>'Libellé du paramètre',
                        'value'=>'$data->Libelle'
                ),
                array(                      
                        'header'=>'Nouvelle donnée?',
                        'name'=>'NewValue',
                        'value'=>'$data->NewValue',                 

                        ),
));
?>
[/code]
```

In my model :

```
[code]

public  function searchByUser($idUser,$role)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->alias = 'Parametre';

        $criteria->join='LEFT JOIN Droit ON Droit.Id_Parametre  = Parametre.Id_Parametre';

        $criteria->compare('Id_Parametre',$this->Id_Parametre,true);
        $criteria->compare('Libelle',$this->Libelle,true);

             ... Other criteria ... 

        $criteria->compare('NewValue',$this->NewValue);

        $sort = new CSort();
        $sort->attributes = array(
                'NewValue'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'NewValue ASC',
                        'desc'=>'NewValue DESC',
                ),
                '*', // this adds all of the other columns as sortable
        );

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'sort'=>$sort,
        ));
    }
[/code]
```

and in the same model My function to see if I have new value :

```
[code]
    public function getNewValue() //mean => hasNewValue()
    {   
        $condition = 'Id_Parametre=:IdParam AND boolValide != 1';
        $params =  array(':IdParam'=>$this->Id_Parametre);
        if(Valeur::model()->exists($condition,$params)!=null)
        {
            return true;
        }   
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
[/code]
```

Whith this, my CGridView is correctly filled, and the header of my "newValue" column is clickable.
But when I click on it I have an sql exception because he don't find the column 'newValue'. 
It's Logic, this column doesn't exist because it is a fonction (getNewValue) .. 
what's wrong? thanks in advance !

here is the error if it is needed :

> [quote]

```
[code]
Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand n'a pas pu exécuter la commande SQL : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'NewValue' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `Parametre`.`Id_Parametre`, `Parametre`.`Libelle`, `Parametre`.`DateDebut`, `Parametre`.`DateFin`, `Parametre`.`Ponderation`, `Parametre`.`Frequence`, `Parametre`.`ValeurCible`, `Parametre`.`Max`, `Parametre`.`BorneVO`, `Parametre`.`BorneOR`, `Parametre`.`Min`, `Parametre`.`Unite`, `Parametre`.`boolIndicateur`, `Parametre`.`Id_Indicateur` FROM `parametre` `Parametre` LEFT JOIN Droit ON Droit.Id_Parametre  = Parametre.Id_Parametre WHERE droit.BoolEncodage = 1 AND droit.Id_User = 0 ORDER BY NewValue ASC LIMIT 10 (D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:543)</p><pre>#0 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php(396): CDbCommand->queryInternal('fetchAll', Array, Array)
#1 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1351): CDbCommand->queryAll()
#2 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1470): CActiveRecord->query(Object(CDbCriteria), true)
#3 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CActiveDataProvider.php(199): CActiveRecord->findAll(Object(CDbCriteria))
#4 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CDataProvider.php(168): CActiveDataProvider->fetchData()
#5 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php(111): CDataProvider->getData()
#6 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\zii\widgets\grid\CGridView.php(339): CBaseListView->init()
#7 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(147): CGridView->init()
#8 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(172): CBaseController->createWidget('zii.widgets.gri...', Array)
#9 D:\WWW\VincentM\PilotTool\protected\views\site\_Encode.phtml(68): CBaseController->widget('zii.widgets.gri...', Array)
#10 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(126): require('D:\WWW\VincentM...')
#11 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(95): CBaseController->renderInternal('D:\WWW\VincentM...', Array, true)
#12 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CController.php(869): CBaseController->renderFile('D:\WWW\VincentM...', Array, true)
#13 D:\WWW\VincentM\PilotTool\protected\views\site\desktop_index.phtml(13): CController->renderPartial('_Encode', Array, true)
#14 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(126): require('D:\WWW\VincentM...')
#15 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php(95): CBaseController->renderInternal('D:\WWW\VincentM...', NULL, true)
#16 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CController.php(869): CBaseController->renderFile('D:\WWW\VincentM...', NULL, true)
#17 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CController.php(782): CController->renderPartial('desktop_index', NULL, true)
#18 D:\WWW\VincentM\PilotTool\protected\controllers\SiteController.php(66): CController->render('desktop_index')
#19 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): SiteController->actionIndex()
#20 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#21 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#22 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#23 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('index')
#24 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('site/index')
#25 D:\WWW\VincentM\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#26 D:\WWW\VincentM\PilotTool\index.php(21): CApplication->run()
#27 {main}</pre>
[/code]
```

> [/quote]

Comment: you can't sort on a attribute that is not stored in database, maybe if you could use some kind of sql expression on that

Comment: What you want is - a column with a Sub Query that either returns `true` or `false`. Then on clicking the link in the `CGridView`, the result should be sorted accordingly. Its more like `SELECT *, (SELECT ...) as NewValue FROM ..`. You do need `public $NewValue;` as a property in the `Parametre` Model class.

Comment: Please check for the use of `SubQuery` in columns in Yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used datatable instead CGridView & dataprovider. It's really more intuitive; simple and clear;

I can't understand all data present in the dataprovider and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may work.

Call 'NewValue' column in table 'Droit' as Droit.NewValue in your CSort().

```
$sort->attributes = array(
            'NewValue'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'Droit.NewValue ASC',
                    'desc'=>'Droit.NewValue DESC',
            ),
            '*', // this adds all of the other columns as sortable
    );
```

Comment: don't work. the table Droit is used to see if the user have the right to see the table Parametre. but the NewValue function is used toi see if the parametre have new record of an other table "Valeur". I tried by adding Droit or Parametre before the call without any success. But if the sql try to look  the field "NewValue' In my mysql DB, it will never find it because it didn't exist in the DB. NewValue only exist in my Parametre model class.